# Can google dataproc access other project's cloud storage using gcs-connector?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to access cross gcp project's cloud storage using hadoop file system APIs to read parquet, avro and sequence files. If i setup a dataproc cluster in a gcp project named "proj1", how can i read cloud storage files in other gcp project named "proj2" using the dataproc cluster in "proj1"?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/service-accounts) to achieve this. Create one, set the permission that you want, on the bucket and the project that you want (use its email address as any email address, as  you could do with a user email address), and that's all!

Comment: In this case, I should create another dataproc cluster in proj2 and associate with the already created service account. But my requirement is to crawl proj2's cloud storage from dataproc cluster in proj1.  core-site.xml contains only one project id which establishes connectivity to a project. So, should different core-site.xmls be created to connect to each project's cloud storage?

Comment: No, create a cluster in project1 with a service account. Then, go to project 2 and either grant the service account with the storage role that you want at the project level (IAM service page); Or, grant the service account with the storage role that you want at the bucket level (Cloud Storage browser page).